# Preview command output to text file before running command (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

I have a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which works as intended, deleting files with a specified string or extension, but I want to keep a record of what was deleted.

I want to take the output of the command and write it to a `.txt` file on my desktop before running the actual command:

```
        if /I %CONFIRM%==y  (
            (del /F /S %FOLDER%\*%DELETE%)>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\deleted.txt"
            del /F /S %FOLDER%\*%DELETE%
        )
```

In this case `%DELETE%` is the user input variable value `bak`.

If I try to delete `.bak` files it still deletes the files but gives me the following result and wont write to text file:

> `Could Not Find C:\Users\USERXYZ\Desktop\*bak`

Any ideas?

Comment: What about listing the files before and after using `Where.exe` or `Dir`, then you should be able to determine those which are no longer there using `FindStr.exe`.

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by "write it to a txt file on my desktop before running the actual command". When you run `del` it will delete the files, there's no "preview mode". Your second `del` doesn't have much sense because the first one already did the job.

Comment: When wishing 'to delete `.bak` files', if '`%DELETE%` is user input var value `bak`', why have you omitted the period, `.`? i.e. `%FOLDER%\*.%DELETE%`, or better still used the correct value in `%DELETE%`, i.e. `.bak`. As for the task, you could delete each file one by one using a loop, and output successful or unsuccessful deletions on that basis, `For /R "%FOLDER%" %%A In ("*%DELETE%")Do Del /A /F "%%A">Nul 2>&1&&(Echo %%A)>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\deleted.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
set /p "confirm=delete %FOLDER%\*%DELETE% ? "
if /I %CONFIRM%==y  (
   (ECHO del /F /S %FOLDER%\*%DELETE%)>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\deleted.txt"
   (dir/S/B %FOLDER%\*%DELETE%)>>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\deleted.txt"
    del /F /S %FOLDER%\*%DELETE%
 )
```

may assist.

In your code, the first `del` command deletes the file AND *should* create the `deleted.txt` file containing the names of the deleted files. Since those files have now been deleted, then the second `del` command quite correctly reports that it could not delete the files since they are no longer there.

Note that `>` will create a NEW file, whereas `>>` will append to an existing file (or create a new file if none already exists)

The `echo del` in this code shows the command that is about to be executed - you may or may not want this - idk. However the `>` puts this into a NEW file.

Comment: you were right, the first delete command wrote the text file and delete the items thank you.